# Teststack.white - How to click the save button in Internet explorer

Tags: white-framework

Browser: Internet explorer

Framework: Teststack.white

Visual studio: 2017 community

(Reproduce:
Navigate to https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/
click manual download)

I use Teststack.white automation framework, I need to press save button in the Internet explorer window.

I could find the toolbar in the page by

```
TestStack.White.UIItems.WindowStripControls.ToolStrip toolStrip = i.e. Get<TestStack.White.UIItems.WindowStripControls.ToolStrip> ("Notification");
```

But not able to identify and click the split button of "Save". I'm able to
click the Open and cancel button.

Comment: Didi you solve this?

Comment: No , i do face the same issue.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your browser window, showing the save button, and perhaps some more code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can't find the Split Button in Watin, so I found an alternate approach. Just pass the `_HdlScreen` as the Watin Current desktop instance, pass the IE Title

```
_HdlScreen = Desktop.Instance.Windows().Find(obj => obj.Title.ToLower().Contains(("My Site - Internet Explorer").ToLower()));

(_HdlScreen.GetElement(TestStack.White.UIItems.Finders.SearchCriteria.ByText("Save")).GetCurrentPattern(System.Windows.Automation.InvokePattern.Pattern) as System.Windows.Automation.InvokePattern).Invoke()
```

It will perform the Click on Save button Event in IE.